# How to stack multiple actions/functions on ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

This is my current ng-click:

```
ng-click="avatarMenu = !avatarMenu"

<div class="avatar"
     ng-click="avatarMenu = !avatarMenu"
     ng-class="{ active: avatarMenu }">
     <img src="_sources/images/joe.png" title="settings" alt="user avatar" />
</div>
```

Now I want to create a $scope function that does something else when you click on that element, tried the following, but got errors:

```
ng-click="avatarMenu = !avatarMenu, getMenuClick('clicked')"
```

Also tried to move the animation/boolean logic into the function inside my app.js but got avatarMenu is not defined, guess since it's not on the HTML anymore:

```
$scope.avatarMenu = false;

$scope.avMenu = {};
$scope.avMenu.getMenuClick = function(the_id) {
    avatarMenu = !avatarMenu
    selectAddress(the_id);
};
```

How would you have both the animate/boolean login on there as well as the function?

Comment: You need to use `$scope.avatarMenu` inside the controller

Comment: I have it in the controller :(

Comment: I meant that you should do: `$scope.avatarMenu  = !$scope.avatarMenu`. Of course, `avatarMenu` is not defined - the controller is just a regular JS function and you don't have `var avatarMenu = false;` there.

Comment: Ah thanks! Want to post that as an Answer? Slowly getting $scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewModel variables defined in the Controller function need to be declared on the `$scope` parameter (as you did) or, if you are using Controller As approach - as the property of the Controller.

So, **with the $scope-approach**:

```
$scope.avatarMenu = ...;
...
  $scope.avatarMenu = !$scope.avatarMenu;
```

and in the View:

```
<div ng-class="{ active: avatarMenu }">
```

or, **with ControllerAs-approach**:

```
this.avatarMenu = ...;
...
   this.avatarMenu = !this.avatarMenu;
```

And in the View:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
   ...
   <div ng-class="{ active: vm.avatarMenu }"></div>
</div>
```

Remember, that at the end of the day, a Controller is just a regular JavaScript function without any "magic" behind it.

Also, as suggested in another answer, you could also use a semi-colon `;` to separate commands in the View, but I would minimize the amount of logic in the View.

Answer (score 1):

Use a semi-colon, instead of a comma.

```
avatarMenu = !avatarMenu; getMenuClick('clicked')
```